# .Rproj file disapeared but project files remain (git shows no changes)

Tags: r, git, github

I've been building an R package via an R project file (.Rproj) in R studio with the project file linked to my github. When I was working on it this morning, all was as it should be, but when I returned to it this afternoon, the .Rproj file had mysteriously vanished. All other files and folders associated with the package are where they should be (e.g., the "R" folder with the scripts for the package's functions, the DESCRIPTION file, the man folder, etc.) but the .Rproj file is gone. I have not deleted it and it is not in my trash can, nor does git have any record of it for some reason.

If I do a search for the file name in the windows search bar (I'm suing windows 7, btw) the file shows up and says that it is in the correct location, but if I click on it, I get an error message saying that the file has been moved or deleted. Similarly, if I try to navigate to where the file should be via "open project" in R, there is a greyed out ".Rproj.user" folder that I don't recall having seen before, but no project file.

I'm at my wits end for what is going on. The package on github appears to all still be correct (as do the files on my computer), but without being able to find or access the .Rproj file I can't easily edit the package and push the changes to github.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on or how to retrieve my package file? Since I have all the source files for it, I could always build a new project using the source files, but then I need that to link up to my github which is linked to a now non-existent project file, and everything becomes really messy and tedious quickly.

PS I have restarted both my computer and R. It didn't help.

Comment: Generally `.Rproj` files are included in `.gitignore` as they are user-specific. You can probably just create a "new" project in that existing folder and get a new .Rproj file.

Comment: @Gregor would that new project file link up to my existing files and github for this project?

Comment: It looks like creating a new .Rproj file in that directory has automatically linked all my files back together and is talking with my github. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably just create a "new" project in the existing folder to generate a new `.Rproj` file.

The `.Rproj` file doesn't actually *do* that much. It mostly lets RStudio know that "this folder is the root directory of a project named X". Git keeps its own hidden files in the directory to track things (that RStudio will look for if it's a project).

If you haven't done this, I'd also recommend adding your `.Rproj` files to your `.gitignore` file - Rproj files are user-specific so shouldn't be tracked in version control. (If you used RStudio to create the git repo, this will be done automatically.)

Comment: I've made a new .Rproj file in that folder, and at first things seemed to be working correctly (I can update files via the .Rproj file and push them to github). However, it does not seem like the new file is linking correctly with the R folder (where the package scripts are stored) because "Build and reload" just reloads the previous version of those files, not the updates. Editing the DESCRIPTION file does result in changes after rebuilding the package, but the changes to the .R files aren't being incorporated.

Comment: Never mind, roxygen had gotten turned off somehow. I think I'm back in business. Thanks.